# Android studio access variable inner class

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I access string value "data" outside class onResponse. Always i use Toast outside class response is display null.

```
String data; 

JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try {

                     data = response.getString("name"));

                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                   }
             }
             }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                queue.add(objectRequest);
}
```

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Display: " + data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: your data will have value after the response comes, response call is asynchronous **so before your response comes you are toasting the data** , hence its null..if you wanna achieve something ..we can help you find the solution..but the data will be filled **only after the response comes..**

Comment: Yes thank you, how can i do?

Comment: inside onResponse call a method and show the toast there..but you have to call in onResponse

Comment: Yes, but if i want call outside onResponse? please help.

Comment: your response will come through internet then u will be able to access it.. **its like saying how can i access internet without connecting to internet**

Comment: you can access it outside only after the response comes..

Comment: I am a beginner developer. I don't know how to access data inner class.

Comment: have a look at ADM 's answer, i was telling you thats its the only process where you get the data accurately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonObjectRequest` which i assume is a volley request is an asynchronous task . So it will run background thread and code on UI thread run as on to end . That's the reason `data` variable is null .

Volley result back the callback on main thread so you can directly show toast or do Update UI inside callback methods .

```
 JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
               String data = response.getString("name"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Display: " + data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**NOTE**:- if you want to define variable `data` previously then it has to be as instance variable(class level) . Because you can not use a non-final local variable inside inner class i.e `Response.Listener` .

Answer (score 1):

You are probably accessing "data" at the wrong time, try showing the toast directly after it has been set, if it says null there aswell, data really is null. ( > and < to show an empty string, if it is empty).

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ">" + data+"<",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: yes, thank you. but i want to use data outside class onRespone. please advice.

Comment: if you want to access a variable that has to be final from the outside, you can do it like this:

`final String[] data = new String[1]`
Then inside of the inner class:
`data[0]= result;`
And finally somewhere where you want to access it:
`Toast.makeText(context, data[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
Hope this helps you.